# Jquery: UL LI does not display text if anchor is attached

Tags: jquery

I'm generating navigation menu from an XML file. Everything works fine expect one issue.

When the menu is generated, the li nodes  (with child nodes and anchor tag attached to it) will not display its text ( based on below example) like 'Web Design', 'Development'. It comes up blank only with list-style-image shown.

But, when I click on image('plusimageapply'), the child nodes are displayed and text "Web Design " is also comes up. Same issue is repeated with every child node that has sub nodes and anchor tag. Only the image shows up without Text. If node is expanded, Text shows up.

When the node is collapsed, the Text disappear again. Image is not effected.

This issue does not happen if the  node does not have a child node or if the node does not have a anchor link  example like "Design".

Can you please help. I have been going nuts not able to know why it is acting like this.

### I'm using IE 10.

HTML Menu layout :

```
<div id=Menu>

<ul>
        <li class="category">Design
            <ul>
                <li><A href="url..." target="somelocation">Graphic Design </A></li>
                <li class="category"><A href="url..." target="somelocation">Web Design </A>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HTML</li>
                        <li>CSS</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Print</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category"><A href="url..." target="somelocation">Development</A>
            <ul>
                <li>PHP</li>
                <li>Java</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
----------------------------------------------------------------
jQUERY: ( used from site:http://www.sendesignz.com/index.php/jquery/77-how-to-create-expand-and-collapse-list-item-using-jquery)

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
    $('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
    $('li.category').children().hide();


    $('li.category').each(
            function (column) {
                $(this).click(function (event) {
                    if (this == event.target) {
                        if ($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
                            $(this).children().show();
                            $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
                            $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).children().hide();
                            $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                            $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');                            
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        );    
});

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CSS:
.plusimageapply
{
    list-style-image: url(../Images/cicon12.png); 
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.minusimageapply
{
    list-style-image: url(../Images/cicon2.png);
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;

}

.selectedimage
{
    list-style-image: url(../Images/cicon9.png);
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple really,

Your first list item is just child text, as such it's not picking up the display:none style as it's part of the li element.

However in your second LI element you are using an anchor for the text, which is a child element of the li, as such it's picking up the display none style,

The javascript is hiding all the children.

$('li.category').children().hide();

And the anchor tag is a child of li.category.

To fix it you need to make the javascript not select the first anchor of a list item.

Here's a new version that works, but you might want to modify it to do this another way, the selectors I'm using might not work on older browsers,

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
$('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
//$('li.category').children().hide();
$('li.category:not(:first-child)).hide();


$('li.category').each(
        function (column) {
            $(this).click(function (event) {
                if (this == event.target) {
                    if ($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
                        $(this).children().show();
                        $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
                        $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).children().hide();
                        $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                        $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');                            
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Ryios. I'm bit new to JQuery. Your answer helped me.

a little modification to the code

$('li.category').children().hide().filter(":first-child").show();